# Did not get data in dropdown which i want in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two tables :

```
Plan (plan_id,plan_name).

Task(task_id,plan_name_id).
```

i want all plan name from plan table in DropDown which are not inserted into task table..

i write this code.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('plan');
$this->db->join('task', 'task.plan_name_id =plan.plan_id');
$res= $this->db->get();
```

But this show only those which are same in both tables.

Comment: Add a where condition that checks that task.column is null. And make sure you're using a left join.

Comment: I write this Condition.
$this->db->where('task.plan_name_id != plan.plan_id');
But then show nothing

Comment: I said, `null`. And again, check it's doing a left join, I don't know codeigniter well enough to say whether what you have is left or inner.

Comment: I will try but still show nothing, can you have alternate in codeigniter.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    $query = "select * from plan where plan.plan_id NOT IN (select task.plan_name_id from task)"
    $res= $this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: run the query directly in mysql and see if you are getting data?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use the Query Builder you can try the following

```
$res = $this->db->select('plan.*')
    ->from('plan')
    ->join('task', 'task.plan_name_id =plan.plan_id', 'left')
    ->where('task.plan_name_id', NULL)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank You Sir!
Now i find other solution for this problem, and i also try this code for more knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Please use left join

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('plan');
$this->db->join('task', 'task.plan_name_id = plan.plan_id', 'left');
$res= $this->db->get();
```